# Spring annotation @RequestParam works with HTML input with type button tag?

Tags: javascript, spring

I try to use several input fields with type "button" for one form. Bellow is a code:

```
<input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Validate" style="margin-right:5px" onclick="
                    doConfirm('<%=prop.getProperty("message.dialog.DatabasePage.OnlyValidation")%>',
                    function yes() {
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                    },
                    function no() {
                    },
                    validateForm()
                    );
                    form.action='/validate-configuration';
                    "/>

            <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Obfuscate" style="margin-left:5px" onclick="
                    doConfirm('<%=prop.getProperty("message.dialog.DatabasePage")%>',
                    function yes() {
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                    },
                    function no() {
                    },
                    validateForm()
                    );
                    form.action='/validate-configuration';
```

And I want to be aware what button was clicked in spring controller:

```
@PostMapping("/validate-configuration")
public String startValidate(@RequestParam("configuration") UUID configurationId,
                            @RequestParam String dataSourceId,
                            @RequestParam String schema,
                            @RequestParam String password,
                            @RequestParam(name = "submitButton") String submitButton,
                            @RequestParam(name = "hashing_salt", defaultValue = "") String hashingSalt,
                            HttpSession session,
                            Map model) {...}
```

But I get an error: "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'submitButton' is not present". And I want to know it's possible to use spring annotation @RequestParam with Html input tags (type "button")?
Please don't offer use type "submit" instead type "button". If I will use type "submit" my confirm dialog box won't work.
I will appreciate for your ideas.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `<button >` tag instead of an `<input type="button"` instead?

Comment: You are right, I will correct my question.

Answer (score 0):

Because @RequestParam doesn't work with Html input tags (type "button") I decided to use some trick. We can add to html markup input tag with type="text" and style="visibility: hidden;" and pass required value through that field. 
Html:

```
<tr>
        <td>



            <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Validate" style="margin-right:5px" onclick="
                    doConfirm('<%=prop.getProperty("message.dialog.DatabasePage.OnlyValidation")%>',
                    function yes() {
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                    },
                    function no() {
                    },
                    validateForm()
                    );
                    $('#validationRequired').val(true);
                    form.action='/validate-configuration';
                    "/>

            <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Obfuscate" style="margin-left:5px" onclick="
                    doConfirm('<%=prop.getProperty("message.dialog.DatabasePage")%>',
                    function yes() {
                    $('#myForm').submit();
                    },
                    function no() {
                    },
                    validateForm()
                    );
                    $('#validationRequired').val(false);
                    form.action='/validate-configuration';
            "/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="validationRequired" type="text" name="validationRequired" style="visibility: hidden;"></input>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Spring controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/validate-configuration")
public String startValidate(@RequestParam("configuration") UUID configurationId,
                            @RequestParam String dataSourceId,
                            @RequestParam String schema,
                            @RequestParam String password,
                            @RequestParam String validationRequired,
                            @RequestParam(name = "hashing_salt", defaultValue = "") String hashingSalt,
                            HttpSession session,
                            Map model) {...}
```

The solution is worked but possible is not better (the security reduces).